# change input maxvalue depending on the selected option

Tags: html, jquery, input

Lets say I got this select tag with 4 rooms:

```
<select name ="room">
   <option value="Room1">Room 1</option>
   <option value="Room2">Room 2</option>
   <option value="Room3">Room 3</option>
   <option value="Room4">Room 4</option>
</select><br>
<label for="guests">Total guests:</label>
<input class="bookinfo" type="number" name="guests" min="1" max="8" placeholder="1-8" required>
```

After this tag, I have an input that shows how many guests can be in each room. However, room 2 is for 10 people and not 8. Is there a way I can change this with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see i create a function check everytime change room `max` and `placeholder` will change:

```js
function CheckGuest(el){
 if(el.value == 'Room2'){
 document.getElementById("bookinfo").max = 10;
 document.getElementById("bookinfo").placeholder = "1-10";

 }else{
  document.getElementById("bookinfo").max = 8;
 document.getElementById("bookinfo").placeholder = "1-8";
 }

}
```

```html
<select name ="room" onChange="CheckGuest(this)">
   <option value="Room1">Room 1</option>
   <option value="Room2">Room 2</option>
   <option value="Room3">Room 3</option>
   <option value="Room4">Room 4</option>
</select><br>
<label for="guests">Total guests:</label>
<input class = "bookinfo" id="bookinfo"   type="number" name="guests" min = "1" max ="8" placeholder="1-8" required>
```

What i change:

- Add `onChange` event for active function everytime you change room
- Add `ID` to `input` for select it with javascript
- Create function for change `max` value and `placeholder`.

i suggest you to read this website [You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Comment: Thanks alot, i wasn't able to make it work with jquery but i guess javascript was a better option in this case:)

Comment: Consider to flag answer and +1  :)

Comment: just a dumb question, but it can also be room 1, shouldn't i write if(el.value == 'Room1' || 'Room2')

Comment: You can add all option you need in if statment. (rember not only `if(el.value == 'Room1' || 'Room2')`  but `if(el.value == 'Room2' || el.value == 'Room3') `

Comment: ah I need to repeat that it's the element value that should be == another room, Got it thanks alot!:)